# SQL Server 2017 JSON Parse object with array into SQL Rows

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm trying to take a JSON object which has an array inside of it, and break it out into corresponding rows.

I Have the following JSON object:

```
{
"CompID":["1","20","22"],
"Date":"21122005",
"ID":"12",
"Total":"5"
}
```

This is what I'm trying to get this from the JSON object:

```
Date        ID  Total   CompID
21122005    12    5     1
21122005    12    5     20
21122005    12    5     22
```

This is my SQL Code:

```
Declare @Json varchar(max) = '{"CompID":["1","20","22"],
"Date":"21122005",
"ID":"12",
"Total":"5"}'

Select A.Date, A.ID, A.Total,
B.CompID
From OpenJson(@Json)
With(
Date varchar(12) 
,ID varchar(10)
,Total varchar(4)
,CompID varchar(3) '$.CompID'
)A
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@Json,'$.CompID')) 
    WITH(CompID NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) B
```

With the above code it returns the three rows that I need, but I get Null values in the CompID column.

```
Date        ID  Total   CompID
21122005    12    5     NULL
21122005    12    5     NULL
21122005    12    5     NULL
```

How do I replace the Null values with the correct CompID numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - just fix the columns definitions in the `OPENJSON()` calls:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @Json varchar(max) = 
'{
   "CompID":[
      "1",
      "20",
      "22"
   ],
   "Date":"21122005",
   "ID":"12",
   "Total":"5"
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   A.Date, 
   A.ID, 
   A.Total,
   b.CompID
FROM OpenJson(@Json) WITH (
   Date varchar(12) '$.Date',
   ID varchar(10) '$.ID',
   Total varchar(4) '$.Total'
) A
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(@Json, '$.CompID') WITH (
   CompID varchar(3) '$'
) B
```

Result:

```
------------------------------
Date        ID  Total   CompID
------------------------------
21122005    12  5       1
21122005    12  5       20
21122005    12  5       22
```

Answer (score 3):

You're pretty close.  You don't reference the JSON again in the APPLY.  You project a JSON column from the first OPENJSON and use that.

Like this:

```
Declare @Json varchar(max) = '
{
 "CompID":["1","20","22"],
 "Date":"21122005",
 "ID":"12",
 "Total":"5"
}'

Select 
  A.Date, 
  A.ID, 
  A.Total,
  --A.CompID,
  cast(B.value as int) CompID 
From OpenJson(@Json)
With
(
     Date varchar(12) 
    ,ID varchar(10)
    ,Total varchar(4)
    ,CompID nvarchar(max) as json
)A
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(CompID) B
```

outputs

```
Date         ID         Total CompID
------------ ---------- ----- -----------
21122005     12         5     1
21122005     12         5     20
21122005     12         5     22
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
  a.Date,
  a.ID,
  a.Total,
  b.CompID
from
  openjson(@js) with (Date varchar(12), ID varchar(10), Total varchar(4)) a
  cross join (select value as CompID from openjson(@js, N'$.CompID')) b
;
```